# Display web service results on a form (Codename One)

Tags: java, netbeans, codenameone

After watching these [videos](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/propertycross-demo.html), I'm trying to do the same but I'm finding it very difficult as I'm using the old GUI Builder. 
I created a form called Form A. I want those results from the web service to display on the form A and be able to navigate upon clicking any of those images just like what happened inside the video.

I'm using the following methods:

private Map response;

```
@Override
    protected void beforeFormA(Form f) {
          getattractive();
         ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) response.get("results");                
                for (Object m:arr){                  
                Map ma = (Map)m;
                address =(String) ma.get("formatted_address");                
                findContainer(f).addComponent(new Label(""+ address ));              
}

        }
```

Connection Request:

```
 private void getattractive(){

         ConnectionRequest r= new ConnectionRequest(){                       
           @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                JSONParser parse= new JSONParser();
                response= parse.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(input));                
                 }                  
           }; 
         String doc="Johor";
       r.setUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="+doc+"+city+point+of+interest&language=en&key=api_key");
       r.setPost(false);
       r.setHttpMethod("GET");                   
       InfiniteProgress prog=new InfiniteProgress();
       Dialog dlg=prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
       r.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);   
       NetworkManager.getInstance(). addToQueueAndWait(r);   
    }
```

First record from the webservice (Attached picture):

Please kindly help.

Regards,

IDE: NetBeans
Desktop OS: Windows 7
Simulator[image]

Comment: I suggest placing a breakpoint on the `response= parse.parseJSON()` line and stepping over that. Then use the debugger inspector tool to see the results in the variable inspector tool in the debugger so you can understand the code you need to write.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks for your response. I did as instructed but I didn't find anything that could lead me to what you had in that video. I saw all the variables I declared, the information inside the connection request method  and some other things which I don't really know how they work. Please see this picture https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/83af2f811689/Slide.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGH2Yh5qK7Tc_IQ2srxI0Ux02nvk4SVZHl9cPnSuSnb7nKTnx5Xokcd7Jf1fHBDmc8t0zlOtMVk5OmMTVgde1Zr049QSn7gP0Q3cIGA_56Zw3RYPJ8

Comment: The in variable which you expanded is the input stream. That won't help you. You need to inspect the response variable **after** the parseJSON method returned the value into it.

Comment: @Shai thanks for your response. I did as instructed and I found all the returned values. Please see the attached pictures (pls see picture 1-4 on discussion forum).
I want to display the picture, name, address, and opening hours in a layout similar to what you have in the video (pls see image1). I was able to display the name and address (pls see image) but I still have issues with the layout and how to display the picture and opening hours.  Additionally, I want when I click on the picture it should open a map and show the location. 
Any assistance on these would be appreciated.

Comment: You are getting a map response, you need to inspect that variable. It will have within it a hierarchy that's identical to the JSON hierarchy you have in the screenshot. Notice that you can embed the actual JSON here instead of using a screenshot...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog thanks for your supports. I tried to inspect the variable as instructed but i'm getting the same results like the ones i posted previously. Please see this (https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/39991c4863fcb/debug2.png?part=0.3&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHBvXjic1i-J6Ti-tve2uj0D9CuOObVmUmqwEVPrXrqr402OXEgBwQWIF0MLm-iVW4ssnQjTMhDWwyendUBDNvSnT64pP2ZvvIB6aLnrJjirQ3UCBc).

Comment: [This image](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/39991c4863fcb/debug2.png?part=0.3&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHsLbQMsumypwUFx-ijbhSCKH0I5z75Z7P2NtbFm2BivamGtiS1rK77UKb7c4uz5vBrkgvCnbfG-YpRF_Ly0pTmHy4WXrrX-Hn6lQdp7Tqz7HcuHKs) literally shows the content of the Map and how the keys correspond to the top level entries in the JSON file. Using get("results") would return an object that will help you dig into the hierarchy. Inspect that object and so forth...

Comment: What im trying to do is to have the output layout like [this](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/3b1b3ff1a4ccf/image1.png?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrF9KtYM32Ekbqf56CIYLjv8Kjx5Qzq0EoBfQssoiiJqT44ppQSFSZpWBX27IJ9IEMck9c0D2g_iQDMM1IIYKIubEsBlGoAJ1OoIGjafKuUEiCVkvuk). Now im having [this](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/3b1b3ff1a4ccf/image.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrGZ5_5L2Jv05vf0OMU0MBYZ-jeqBGBgikOmOtBagx0cBDiv11a8b5ok-R5H8wRO0HmBpTEUbhEvjKIvAbh0lv1lbwvZf1ml4IIA_P2UOT9be0JrgFg) and I want when I click on the image it should open up the location on a map.

Comment: I don't see the problem, you get access to the variables now just create UI components based on the values you got back. What's the issue?

Comment: Hi Shai, What i'm trying to do is to have the output layout like this [image](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/297b925b47b5/image3.png?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHrx3zRu6-2PtSFVyKcCBffV3QULdYC7-MB6MmioPqHs4q_NoKYhpEL2RUCOKl6tcGn86b0iOWfR3XbH4ea9B1oZ7ANu_rokVaL9_vSzBHFJMf7fMM). Currently i'm having this [image](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/297b925b47b5/image.png?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrEyF4DnEKwKx2w8kxrZa0BbYvbvUxg3fv_MBcOBc3XhlE7TGacjRvJGdiE5HzsUKPQFpXEfNgkjnWzxBc1lCSx6_iigZn_-LKfg3ewOdkLX7HV5xG4)

Comment: ArrayList arr = (ArrayList) response.get("results");                
                for (Object m:arr){                  
                Map ma = (Map)m;              
                Container c1 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));                     
                address =(String) ma.get("formatted_address");
                name=(String)ma.get("name");
                c1.addComponent(new Label(""+ name ));
                c1.addComponent(new Label(""+ address ));
                findContainer(f).addComponent(c1);                   
    }         
}

Comment: and I want when I click on the [Photo](https://05360592106309013684.googlegroups.com/attach/297b925b47b5/image3.png?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHrx3zRu6-2PtSFVyKcCBffV3QULdYC7-MB6MmioPqHs4q_NoKYhpEL2RUCOKl6tcGn86b0iOWfR3XbH4ea9B1oZ7ANu_rokVaL9_vSzBHFJMf7fMM) it should open up the location on a map

Comment: Did you look at what we did in property cross? The code is one file, it's not hard to adapt that logic to match yours. If something isn't clear I suggest asking a question like "What does this code in Property Cross Do" and point at a specific block of code that isn't clear. I tried to comment everything and there is also this course in Udemy where I explain every line https://www.udemy.com/learn-mobile-programming-by-example-with-codename-one/